# The Collected of the awaitReaction doesn't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

im making a help command for my bot in discord using the awaitReaction with the discord.js 13.6.0.
It's not the first time i ask about this but now i know wheres is the error but i dont know how can i fix this.
Heres my code of the filter and the await reaction:

```js
    message.reply({embeds:[embed]}).then((m) => {
      m.react('1️⃣');
      m.react('2️⃣');
      m.react('3️⃣');
          const filter = (user, reaction) => user.id === message.author.id && ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
          m.awaitReactions({filter,  max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
          .then(collected => {
            //using the console.log() before the collected works but using the console.log() here even after the user reacts the message doesn't work
            //the part of the embeds and the collected.first().emoji.name
            })
            .catch(collected => {
            return;
          });
        });
```

The way i discovered was just using a console.log("something") inside the code.

Comment: Is the message you react to cached? (i.e. sent after the bot was logged in) Have you added partials?

Comment: i think is a yes